# NFL game in which a team scores a late TD to pull within one point and then attempts a two-point conversion?

Tags: nfl, history

Has there ever been a regular season or playoff game in the NFL in which a team trailed by 7 points in the final 2 minutes, scored a touchdown to pull within one point, and instead of kicking the extra point, they attempted a two-point conversion?

Comment: If anyone has more time than me and wants to put together a definitive list, here are all games post-merger where a team scored at least 6 points in the 4th quarter, went for a 2pt conversion at some point during the game, and had a final point differential of 1.

Comment: Not all of these will fit the criteria, but everything that fits the criteria would be in this list.  https://www.pro-football-reference.com/play-index/tgl_finder.cgi?request=1&match=game&year_min=1970&year_max=2019&game_type=E&game_num_min=0&game_num_max=99&week_num_min=0&week_num_max=99&temperature_gtlt=lt&c1stat=points_diff&c1comp=eq&c1val=1&c2stat=two_pt_att&c2comp=gte&c2val=1&c3stat=quarter_4_score_tgl&c3comp=gte&c3val=6&c5val=1.0&order_by=quarter_4_score_tgl

Comment: @kuhl your query does not include these games that fit my criteria: [game1](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game/_/gameId/401128120), [game2](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game?gameId=401128121), [game3](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game/_/gameId/320101034)

Comment: Weird...  I can't seem to get those games to show up no matter how I change that query.  Well, nevermind then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One game springs to mind:

[Tennessee Titans 19 - 20 LA Chargers, Wembley Stadium, 2018-10-21](https://www.espn.co.uk/nfl/game?gameId=401030792)

The Titans were trailing by 7 going into the 2 minute warning. With 31 seconds left, Marcus Mariota found TE Luke Stocker for a 1 yard TD. The Titans head coach Mike Vrabel elected to go for a two-point try to win the game, that subsequently failed.

Answer (score 4):

I came across some more non-playoff games while trying to find out if it has ever happened in a playoff game (I am 99.9% certain it has not, but I have no citation):

- The first time it happened was in [Week 15 of 2002](http://www.startribune.com/chargers-chiefs-finish-was-first-of-its-kind-since-vikings-saints-in-2002/502758322/), when the Vikings were successful on a 2-point conversion (despite Daunte Culpepper [fumbling the snap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p8AooXvKVn0)) with 5 seconds left against the Saints and won 32-31.
- The Texans were unsuccessful on a 2-point conversion with 14 seconds left against the Titans in [Week 17 of 2011](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game/_/gameId/320101034) and lost 23-22.
- The Raiders were successful on a 2-point conversion with 47 seconds left against the Saints in [Week 1 of 2016](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game/_/gameId/400874543) and won 35-34.
- The Vikings were successful on a 2-point conversion with no time left against the 49ers in the [preseason of 2017](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game/_/gameId/400950235) and won 32-31.
- The Chargers were successful on a 2-point conversion with 4 seconds left against the Chiefs in [Week 15 of 2018](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game?gameId=401030874) and won 29-28.
- The Broncos were successful on a 2-point conversion with 31 seconds left against the Bears in [Week 2 of 2019](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game/_/gameId/401128120) to take a 14-13 lead, but lost 16-14 after the Bears made a field goal as time expired.
- The Dolphins were unsuccessful on a 2-point conversion with 6 seconds left against the Redskins in [Week 6 of 2019](https://www.espn.com/nfl/game?gameId=401128121) and lost 17-16.